# Django 1.7: how to make ManyToManyField required?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, many-to-many

I have a Django Model with `ManyToManyField` in it. I need to require user to select at least one M2M value in this field.

I tried to set `blank=False` to M2M field but it didn't help.

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PersonSkills(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    skill = models.ForeignKey('Skill')

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField('Skill', through='PersonSkills')

p = Person(name='Bob')
p.save()
# success, but I expect that this should throw ValidationError, because I didn't select at least one Skill for this person
```

I can solve this situation with custom `Form` definition or with override `save()` method for `Person` model.

Is it possible to prevent create `Person` without at least one `Skill` selected, with set `ManyToManyField` options? Or I need to create custom logic to handle this situation? Thanks.

I use `Django 1.7` and `Python 3.4`

---

**Update 1.** How to create `ModelForm` to control M2M? Because in `cleaned_data` I have only fields that I pass for `Person` form, and haven't data that I pass as M2M fields. I try to create object in Admin Site and control that `Skills` selected. I enter `Skill`'s via `inline`.

```
# admin.py
class PersonSkillsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Person.skills.through
    extra = 2

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PersonSkillsInline]

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Comment: You'll need to make sure you have at least one value through a ModelForm class for Person.

Comment: @Brandon I agree. But if I will try to create the  `Person` object without use custom `Form` this will allow me to create user without `Skill` selected :-(

Comment: How else do you want to be able to create the record? I'm not quite understanding why you wouldn't use a ModelForm...

Comment: @Brandon thank you. I didn't imagine that we use intermediate model with specified both `ForeignKey` fields in it. In this case I can't control M2M field by pass options to M2M field. I will use ModelForm with `clean()` method in it to check if `skills` passed.

Comment: I have updated my question. Figure out how to use Admin Site and check count of Skill objects as inline's.

Comment: `skills` should be present in the `cleaned_data` dictionary of a `ModelForm` for a Person. It's a field on the model. why wouldn't it be there? Unless you've explicitly added it to the `excludes` tuple of the form class.

Comment: I use `inline` in Django Admin. And on validation stage I haven't m2m object yet, because to create m2m I need to create this object first.

Comment: so, if I understand you correctly, you're specifying `Skill` as an inline model of a `PersonSkill` and then making an m2m association of a `PersonSkill` to a `Person`?

Comment: Added `admin.py` contents

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a database level... no, that's not possible. Any enforcement of this will have to come from your application logic.

The reason is that every m2m relation has a record with a foreign key *to* both sides of the m2m relation. SQL cannot enforce the existence of the referencing side of a relationship, only of the referenced side of a relationship.

Furthermore, you can't enforce it in your model either, because the `Person` has to be created and saved before you can assign any many-to-many relations.

Your only options are to enforce it in the form or the view.

In an `InlineModelAdmin` this can easily be done by specifying [`min_num`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.min_num) (1.7+):

```
class PersonSkillsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Person.skills.through
    min_num = 1
    extra = 2
```

Comment: Yes, I agree... Thanks for explanation, now I understand that I haven't control of this in Model side, and need to create custom ModelForm and use `clean()` method to check `skills` in it.

Comment: @AntonDanilchenko See the addition to my answer.