# Complex Django model relationships

Tags: sql, django, database, django-models

I'm trying to build an SQL database for use in Django. I understand the model from an abstract perspective, but I don't know enough about how to build databases to know if I'm relating these objects correctly. I want to keep this abstract so I can implement the code myself.

Say I have three types of objects: `A`, `B`, and `C`. An `A` may hold one or more `B`. A `B` can hold multiple `B`s or `C`s in any combination, but it must have at least one (`B` or `C`) inside of it. A `C` merely holds some data and is a simple construct.

Currently I have:

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    # A attributes

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # B attributes

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # C attributes
```

I know that this just allows a Many-To-One relationship between `C`→`B` and `B`→`A`, but I don't know how to allow a `B` to refer to another `B`.

I would also like to be able to easily write a form where you start with an `A` with a requirement of at least one `B` inside of it, and you can add or remove `B`s at will. Is this possible?

I think there's probably just a better way of setting up this data, but I don't see it since I'm very new to database organization.

---

If it helps, I'm designing a form to allow easy writing of workouts for swimming. The `A` is a workout, which has a title and an author. Each `B` is a set. Sets are composed of things like "2x50yards freestyle" or "8x100 IM on 2:00" — the `C`s. But sometimes a set has sort of a sub-set, which is like a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend checking out the Django documentation on models which can be found here: [Django Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/)

Moreover, to make a symmetrical Many to Many relationship, use:

```
class B(models.Model):
    bs = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

Additionally, I recommend making the relationship between A and B a many to many relationship instead of a foreign key. This will allow you to assign the B to many A's while still allowing 1 A to have many B's. The same logic should potentially be taken for B and C.

To answer your question about making B's required for A, I do not think this is possible. Check out this question for more information: [Django 1.7: how to make ManyToManyField required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840621/django-1-7-how-to-make-manytomanyfield-required)

Comment: Ah, okay. Those are good suggestions. I'll check that out. However... I'm curious about making the A and B relationship a many-to-many. If the Bs are identified by their primary key (a number), when would I ever see multiple As refer to the same B?

Comment: If you have the same set that can be used in 2 different workouts, you only want to create 1 database entry. A many to many relationship allows for this, while a foreign key would require you to make a new identical entry into the sets every time you want to add it to a new workout

Comment: Hmm okay, but how does the database determine that they're the same? As a user, you won't ever select from pre-existing sets (although... well maybe that could be a feature, but it wasn't intended). The way I had imagined it was: somebody will fill out a form to write a workout, and then the workout will be posted for other people to read. It's unlikely that workouts will ever be edited or portions reused readily. (I'm not trying to say I dislike your suggestion; I just don't know enough to know whether our thoughts are lining up!)

Comment: If you're just planning on doing it like that, to be honest, I don't see the point in creating multiple tables at all. I would just have one table where you can add a 'workout' field which would be a text representation of the entire workout. Adding many to many fields allows for easy scalability and prevents unnecessary repetition in the database

Comment: Oh, I see! I'm just so used to OOP. So kind of serialize the data to fit it into one textfield (per set) and expand it as needed? That actually does make a lot of sense. Thank you!